# The ways to make selenium faster

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to grab some information on the one site, where I need to get phone numbers. The full telephone number is hidden, so to search for the full number I need to use selenium. However, it needs to sleep for 0.2 seconds(found it empirically). I have 10000 phones to parse, so alltogether it works a lot of time and I don't have so to wait. How I can make it much faster?

My current code now is the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/admin/Downloads/chromedriver')
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@class="show-phones"]')
link[0].click()
#tel = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "offer__contacts-phones"]//p')
sleep(0.2)
#tel = driver.find_element_by_class_name('offer__contacts-phones')
tel = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "offer__contacts-phones"]')
#ex = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

cur = tel.text
driver.quit()
```

It works, but for 1 page it works kind of 3 seconds, which is a lot.

Comment: You need to create a pagination system and have different (or threads) for each page. Also, there's a headless Selenium I think, that should make it faster as well

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible points to optimize:

- Start from switch from xpath to css locators. They work the way faster.
- Try to "play" with querying bunches of elements and parse the collection in your code.
- Parallelize your code. You could make your threads process a single page or a bunch of pages.
- Check different browsers. Some might work faster in certain cases.
- Check headless modes. Such mode might work faster in certain cases.
- Avoid constant sleep time. Use waiter utilities allowing to tune total waiting using conditions.

Comment: Just adding to this answer, you should also get rid of sleeps, instead use methods to wait for a locator to visible on the page

Comment: @AutoTester213 thnx! Added.